# Spring boot launched in Storm Bolt disables logging to worker log

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback, apache-storm

I have added spring boot to my bolt and everything is working fine except the fact that logging gets lost the moment I run SpringApplication.run on the cluster. I can not see the logs in my worker log directory for storm. The odd part is that this works fine in localmode (i can see it in console.out) but does not work when deployed to the storm cluster.

```
public class TestBolt extends BaseBasicBolt {
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestBolt.class);
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration 
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.test")
static class SpringApplication1 {

    @Autowired
    static TestService testServiceInstance;

    public static void main(String[] args){

       testServiceInstance.logthis("I CANT SEE THIS");
        LOGGER.info("I CANT SEE THIS ASWELL");
    }
}

@Component
static class TestService{
    public String logThis(String t){
        LOGGER.info(t);
        return t;
    }
}



@Override
public void execute(Tuple tuple, BasicOutputCollector collector) {

    LOGGER.info(" I CAN SEE THIS");
    SpringApplication.run(TestBolt.SpringApplication1.class, new String[]{});
}
```

}

Comment: Is your logger configuration the same on each node in the cluster as on you local machine?

Comment: I do not think so. I believe locally it is using log4j.properties in my resources folder of my uberjar. I believe on the cluster storm is using the cluster.xml ? Im using a hortonwork distribution 2.2.1

Comment: I am not familiar with Hortonworks distribution. But I would assume that the logs go somewhere else or logging is disabled or whatever... You should try to figure out how Hortonworks does configure Storm (or try to customize the configuration to your needs).

Comment: The issue im running into is that line LOGGER.info(" I CAN SEE THIS"); will log properly. The moment spring turns on all logging goes away. The logs do not write anywhere. Its as if spring has its own logging system enabled.